# Directly import next.js API endpoint in getServerSideProps()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When fetching data using `getServerSideProps()` in Next.js, they recommend directly importing the API endpoint instead of using `fetch()` and running another HTTP request. This makes sense, and I was able to get it working until implemented middleware for my API (note, I'm using the API feature built into Next.js). Now with middleware implemented, I can't export functions that use the middleware, I have to export the handler. See below:

```
const handler = nextConnect();
handler.use(middleware);

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
    const post = await req.db.collection("posts").findOne();
    res.send({
        post: post,
    });
});

export default handler;
```

What would be the recommend way to import my API endpoint into getServerSideProps? I would like to do something as follows, but the `getPost()` function no longer has access to the database middleware:

```
export const getPost = async () => {
    const post = await req.db.collection("posts").findOne();
    return post;
}

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        post: getPost(),
    });
});
```

and then in my next.js page:

```
import { getPost } from './api/post';
...
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    return {
        props: {
            post: getPost(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you give me more info on the setup of your project, in particular your database, I can totally solve the problem for you and earn that bounty ;)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, you'll have to pass the `req` and `res` objects to the function. But if you do the following, the `post` prop should be populated with a `NextApiResponse` instance, which at it's base is a `stream.Writable` object, which is probably not what you want...

```js
import { getPost } from './api/post';
...
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {
  return {
    props: {
      post: await getPost(req, res),
    }
  }
}
```

You could try to read the stream, but that seems like more trouble than refactoring your code, but if you call `getPost(req, res).end()`, I think you should get the streamed data, but I'm not sure how it will be formatted. You'd have to check.

You could split your functions up a little more..

```js
// In your api endpoint:
const handler = nextConnect();
handler.use(middleware);

export async function getPostMethod(db) {
  return await db.collection("posts").findOne();
}

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    post: await getPostMethod(req, res, req.db)
  })
});

export default handler;

// In your page component:

export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}) {
  // Do what ever you have to do here to get your database connection
  const db = await whereIsMyDb()
  return {
    props: {
      post: await getPostMethod(db),
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm still a little unclear how to get the db instance inside getServerSideProps(). You have the function "whereIsMyDb", but when dealing with middleware, how would that function return the db instance?

Comment: Which database are you using and how are did you configure it in your app?

Comment: The question is: Why to you need middleware to connect to your database?